# fail to connect localhost:8081 using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have opened the server.js and the address:http://localhost:8081 on my browser. But then a text "Upgrade Required" appeared at the top left conern of the website.
What is the problem of that? What else do I need to upgrade?

Here is the server.js:

```
var serialport = require('serialport');
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;

var SERVER_PORT = 8081;
var wss = new WebSocketServer({
    port: SERVER_PORT
});
var connections = new Array;

SerialPort = serialport.SerialPort,
portName = process.argv[2],
serialOptions = {
    baudRate: 9600, 
    parser: serialport.parsers.readline('\n')
};
if (typeof portName === "undefined") {
    console.log("You need to specify the serial port when you launch this script, like so:\n");
    console.log("    node wsServer.js <portname>");
    console.log("\n Fill in the name of your serial port in place of <portname> \n");
    process.exit(1);
}

var myPort = new SerialPort(portName, serialOptions);

myPort.on('open', showPortOpen);
myPort.on('data', sendSerialData);
myPort.on('close', showPortClose);
myPort.on('error', showError);

function showPortOpen() {
    console.log('port open. Data rate: ' + myPort.options.baudRate);
}

function sendSerialData(data) {
    if (connections.length > 0) {
        broadcast(data);
    }
}

function showPortClose() {
    console.log('port closed.');
}

function showError(error) {
    console.log('Serial port error: ' + error);
}

function sendToSerial(data) {
    console.log("sending to serial: " + data);
    myPort.write(data);
}

wss.on('connection', handleConnection);

function handleConnection(client) {
    console.log("New Connection");
    connections.push(client);

    client.on('message', sendToSerial);
    client.on('close', function () {
        console.log("connection closed");
        var position = connections.indexOf(client);
        connections.splice(position, 1);
    });
}
function broadcast(data) {
    for (c in connections) {
        connections[c].send(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `server.js` ? Show the code. Some console output might be useful too.

Answer (score 1):

OK, websockets...

The "upgrade required" status marks the start of a websocket handshake. Normally your client sends this first to the WS server. The server answers in a pretty similar manner (details here : https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455 ), and then proceed to pipe the actual data.

Here, you're opening a connection from your client as regular http, sending a simple GET. What you see on the screen is the server dumbly proceeding with an already corrupted handshake.

That's not how you open a WS client side connection. You don't usually open WS pages from the browser. It ought to be opened from a JavaScript call, such as `new WebSocket(uri)`. So what you want is a regular http server on another port, that serves a page containing the necessary Javascript to open the actual WS connection and do something useful with its data. You'll find a clean example here : http://www.websocket.org/echo.html

Comment: I have a html with javascript and i coded var socket = new WebSocket("http://localhost:8081");

Comment: Is that the context in which the "upgrade required" message appeared ?

Comment: yeah, that is the html i want to use. But it just not showing the HTML i  want

Comment: Your situation is extremely unclear to me. You need to serve the .html on a regular http port, not on your 8081 websocket. Is that the case ?

Comment: [link]http://www.tigoe.com/pcomp/code/arduinowiring/1096/ 
This is the tutorial that i followed. Hope it would help

Comment: By not attempting a http GET on 8081 / not writing that URL in the browser's address bar.